# Pagination with UiScrollview and rendering the next page

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, pagination, redraw

I have implemented the UIScrollView with pagination, according to the PhotoScroller example.

However, I cannot get it to work nicely. I use an viewController which loads an XIB. But when scrolling the page does not actually update until it is complete in view (so it doesn't seem to render the layout with the data until it is completely in view)

I load the data on Loadview (as viewWillAppear never seems to be called in this scenario).
Any suggestions how I can have the whole view rendered when it is created so it shows while scrolling towards it? I am at a loss and think I tried almost everything (except the obvious probably).

(edit: the views that were loaded are stored in a mutable dictionary for recall when scrolling back, and they for correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was to implement the example App and instead of only loading the pages around the current page when scrolling starts, to preload the pages around. That seems to work perfect.